# QGIS opening file - very slow on PostGIS database with many layers

Tags: qgis, postgis

When opening a QGIS file with many layers (20 or so) it takes +5 minutes to load. All the layers come from a single PostGIS database.

When looking into the server logs, I see that there are many requests like:

```
LOG:  SELECT typname,typtype,typelem,typlen FROM pg_type WHERE oid=1700
LOG:  SELECT pg_catalog.format_type(atttypid,atttypmod) FROM pg_attribute WHERE attrelid=34757 AND attnum=3
LOG:  SELECT description FROM pg_description WHERE objoid=34757 AND objsubid=3
```

Since there are thousands (+3000) of these queries, I suppose the problem lies there...

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that this problem occurs only when the layers are inserted through "Add vector layer->Database->PostgreSQL". In this case QGIS uses the OGR provider to communicate with PostgreSQL database. There seems to be a bug in the implementation of the OGR provider in QGIS>1.8 causing reopenings of the dataset for every record and every table (thus thousands of querries).

The described problem should not occur if the layers are added with "Add PostGIS layers", since in that case QGIS uses its native PostgreSQL provider which does not have the bug. This is at least my experience and the explanations I received from the developers at gdal-dev and qgis-developers mailing lists:

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Problems-with-MySQL-queries-in-GDAL-td5204406.html
and

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Problem-with-the-MySQL-GDAL-implementation-in-QGIS-td5204626.html

Comment: This works great in 2.18. In 3.6 it appears to have regressed, however.

Answer (score 0):

Do your various tables in you DB have spatial indexing??

for more info go to [what is spatial indexing](http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/indexing.html)

That could be a solution

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but all the tables have spatial indexing enabled. 
I read somewhere that it has to do with the PostGreSQL provider that is being used in QGIS.
Apparantly it is not an issue in qgis 1.8 and earlier. I'll reply back here when i have more information.